# Why my code in c++ is taking too long to execute?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

When I click to compile and run my code in C++, using Dev-C++, the code takes a while to run in the console, even though it's something very basic. The console screen opens and goes black, with the cursor blinking, the program only starts after a few seconds. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int valor[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "digite valor[" << i << "]" << endl;
        cin >> valor[i] ;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "valor[" << i << "]: " << valor[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: on my computer you code compiles and runs almost instantly. What is 'dev c++'? and what are you running it on?

Comment: I guess this probably has nothing to do with your code. Can you write a simple "Hello World" program to see if it takes that long ? (It may have something to do with your computer RAM or other things ?)

Comment: It is not uncommon for aggressive virus scanners to delay running an unknown application while it is scanned.

Comment: I recall DevC++ a little. It is a horrible environment by any standard. Please check out CLion or something more comprehensive.

Comment: If you could see first output `digite valor[0]`. You need to input in your console.

The code `cin >> valor[i] ;` is waiting for your input from stdin, so the program is blocked.

Comment: You mention "the console screen opens and goes black".    Whatever approach you're using to start your program is probably the cause of delay - for example, if launching it within the IDE, clicking an icon.    It appears something else (like a console window or a command prompt) is being started, and your program then being run in the context of that "something else".      That "something else", if being done every time you run your program, will explain why you keep seeing the delay.

Comment: DevC++ is a very, very old Windows-oriented C++ IDE. Most likely, it is bundled with a very, very old g++ compiler. Please consider installing something newer.

Comment: Are you launching the application or are you launching a debugger that subsequently starts the debuggee?

Comment: At my prior job, I was always annoyed at how slow our program was to save files. When I debugged it, I found that like 80% of the time was spent in File.Close. On a hunch, I made the antivirus ignore our save folder, and suddenly our app could save files 5x faster :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a similar issue some years ago at work, with the imposed antivirus. All compiled executables, even the smaller one, took several seconds to really be launched.

We were forced to request some special rights to IT in order to be able to exclude from scanning our development folders. It solved the problem instantly.

You should be able to tell your antivirus to exclude your base development folder (let's say `"C:\Users\malkmim\Projects"` and all its subfolders) from scan, and then test again if you still have this issue.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Apparently, Mcafee does not allow to exclude a whole folder from scanning, so I had to disable it temporarily. Thank you and the others for your time.

Comment: @malkmim At least you know why, but it's a shame that McAfee don't allow that - and their argument for that is quite fallacious: _"Malware can spot an excluded folder and dump its contents in there."_ And worst, removable media CAN be ignored... Usually, you never ignore removable media and download folders, they chose to allow to ignore one major malware entry point, but decided to refuse exclusions because of malwares? They are special... Maybe you should seek for another antivirus?

Comment: I don't remember which antivirus it was, but we had one that would run the program in a sandbox and if it decided that it was "safe" then run it for real. It made running with the debugger automatically attached impossible. You needed to put a busy loop at the beginning of the program, wait for the second one to pop up, then attach the debugger and break the busy loop. They wondered why all of our estimates suddenly doubled...

Answer (score 0):

you should check your antivirus application , and then desable 'real-time protection' for a while until you finish your work.

Comment: This answer might be improved by mentioning which antivirus application calls that feature 'real-time-protection'. Others call it 'On access scan' or similar. However, as the other answer points out, if possible exclude only specific folders instead of disabling it completely.